# Нужна ли запятая в этом случае?

Tags: пунктуация

Первое, что бросается в глаза(,) - мрачность произведения.

Answer (score 5):

Первое, **что бросается в глаза**, ― (это) мрачность произведения.

Запятая нужна, но лучше ещё добавить связку ЭТО.

**"Первое"** ― субстантивированное порядковое числительное в роли подлежащего, оно распространено придаточным предложением, которое обособляется запятыми; "мрачность" ― сущ. в И. п. в роли именной части сказуемого.